# Reference request: $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$ is compactly embedded in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, compactness, bochner-spaces

On a bounded domain $\Omega$, I am looking for a reference saying that $L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))$ is compactly embedded in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$.

I tried all the usual texts (Showalter, Evans, Boyer & Fabrie..).

Comment: It might help if you list "all the usual texts" you checked.

Comment: What makes you think that this is true? For example for $\Omega = (0,1)$, let $f_n (x)(t) = e^{2\pi i nt}$. Then this should have no convergent subsequence in $L^2(\dots)$, because it converges weakly to 0, but not in norm. Basically, your claim would entail $L^\infty(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^2(\Omega)$ as a compact embedding, which is not true.

Comment: @PhoemueX See this thread http://mathoverflow.net/questions/196564/identifying-the-weak-limit-of-a-gradient-bochner-spaces and the comments.. Now i'm confused.

Comment: @ChrisAl: I commented on the other thread.